# Business card reader for iPhone/Android

Tags: business-card

Every time I meet someone new in the working world, he/she will pass me their business card and I will always misplaced it. (I am sure this happens to many others, too)

I have tried looking for business card readers but most of them are paid and I am not sure of the quality of the apps

**Must have:**

- stores the info from business card in the phone by taking a photo
- very accurate
- works on Android or iOS

**Desirable:**

- Free (but I don't mind paying a bit if I must)

Answer (score 1):

## [CamCard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.BCRLite)

Usage: Use the phone camera to take a photo of a business card. The app crops the picture, recognizes the text fields, inputs them in a form, then asks to confirm the information and save in contacts. Features:

- "Stores the info from business card in the phone by taking a photo" **Yes**
- "Very accurate" **Yes**. I tested it on half a dozen cards around the desk. It made one reading mistake because of a ligature in a company's name. I'd say that doesn't count<sup>1</sup>
- "Works on Android or iOS" **Both**
- "Free" **Limited**. Free for 200 scans. The [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.BizCardReader) is (currently) for 0.75€ ($0.99). It also has several added features, like an in-app camera for better accuracy

---

<sup>1</sup>*Edit*: Currently testing it on more cards. It also didn't correctly capture a multi-line email address (It added the second part in the webpage field).

Verdict: Pretty accurate, with a couple exceptions. I'm not sure such cases can be fixed with present technology. Business cards are still targeted towards human eyes, and I don't expect an app to be able to decode superimposed letters or tell the difference between `example.com` and 
`john.doe@
example.com`

Answer (score 0):

[TouchBase Business Cards](http://www.touchbase-technologies.com/):

*Allow others to instantly save contact info. Share videos and brochures. Identify who has tapped your card. Just tap and go - all without NFC.*

**Features**:

- Make it easier for others to connect with you: With one tap of your card, they can email you, call you, connect with you on LinkedIn, and follow you on Twitter.  Next time they need to reach you, they know where to find you.
- Share more information than ever before: People should not have to go on a wild goose chase to get the information they need.  Upload brochures, videos, photos, and links and make it all accessible in one place.
- Update your information anytime: Whether you've changed companies or simply want to update your profile picture, your contacts will be notified with any changes.
- Track who has tapped your card: Use your business card as a CRM tool.  Assess customer interest and track sales leads with tap data.

More information from their [Indiegogo Campaign](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/touchbase-business-cards-tap-go-business-cards).

Please Note:

- May be currently supported by iOS only at present, other platforms to come in near future.
- Currently available for Pre-Order only.

Comment: The asker wants to store info of ALL received business cards. I guess less than 0.001% are compatible with the technology you describe.

Comment: The first link leads to a Japanese site - is this the correct one, or did the owner change? The second link (indiegogo) is 404 now.