# Business card storage/search for Android, works offline

Tags: gratis, android, offline, ocr, business-card

I need to store business cards and find them later by search.

Requirements:

- Take picture (sometimes two-sides)
- Save picture at appropriate resolution/compression (kilobytes rather than megabytes)
- OCR the text and index it.
- Let me search for a string of characters, or a date.
- Free, ideally Open source
- Does not send data to any server. Sending data to a self-hosted (by me) server is OK.
- Back up via SD card or USB cable or to my self-hosted server, in a non-obfuscated format.

Bonus:

- Chronology of business cards, in order I scanned them, with dates.

If OCR is too difficult to do on Android, doing it on my computer (Tesseract?) is acceptable as well.

Comment: Similar but different, with no applicable solution: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/business-card-reader-for-iphone-android

Comment: I have not tried any of them myself (no need), but you might take a look at [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=18#group_77). Most of them OCR the scanned card to your contacts list, but at least [CamCard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.intsig.BCRLite) seems to keep pictures (according to the screenshots). What makes an answer impossible is the condition "not send data to any server". I didn't encounter any app where that was made clear. Backup could always be done via Helium & FolderSync.

Comment: Meanwhile… [ScanBizCards](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scanbizcards): "business card reader app that gives you the option to scan the card on your phone ***OR*** submit the card for a 100%-accurate manual transcription". Sounds like your candidate. Free version available, and a paid one for one buck.